# ListView items drawn on top of each other when scrolling (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, parse-platform

In a fragment, I have a ListView that has a custom `ParseQueryAdapter<T>`. The problem may not have anything to do with Parse, although I'm not sure.

As I was testing my app, I noticed something very strange. When I would scroll down my ListView, all the visible ListView items would be drawn on top of the next ListView item as seen in the second image below.

The list initialized properly as such:

[image: Initialized correctly]

As you can see, in my list item layout, I have an ImageView (`ParseImageView` to be specific) and a TextView. The TextView now displays some notes (don't mind the ID `user_name_text_view`) and the ImageView displays a placeholder blank profile picture.

When I scrolled down, the list looked like:

[image: Stacked View here]

Here's my **list view layout** named `fragment_post_view_list_view`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/post_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my **list item layout** named `list_item_post_view`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/link_blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my **adapter** named `PostViewListViewAdapter`:

```
public class PostViewListViewAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Post> {
    // call superclass with a query to populate list view
    public PostViewListViewAdapter(Context context, final String[] postsObjectIds) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post>(){
            public ParseQuery<Post> create() {
                ParseQuery<Post> query = Post.getQuery();
                query.whereContainedIn("objectId", Arrays.asList(postsObjectIds));
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    // this is similar to getView method in an adapter
    @Override
    public View getItemView(Post post, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_post_view, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(post, v, parent);
        TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name_text_view);
        usernameTextView.setText(post.getNotes()); // some string

        return v;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Is this an issue with *XML* or *Java*?

I was following the two tutorials from Parse and the [example from the Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-queryadapter):

- [MealSpotting](https://parse.com/tutorials/mealspotting)
- [Parse Query Adapter](https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter)

I set the adapter and ListView here:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_view_list_view, container, false);
mPostsObjectIds = SOME_STRING[];

PostViewListViewAdapter adapter = new PostViewListViewAdapter(getActivity(), mPostsObjectIds);

ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.post_list_view);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I've tried getting rid of the `ParseImageView` in my list item layout, but my TextViews still draw on top of each other when I scroll.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that the list items display on top of each other *after* an orientation change.

I tested this on my Galaxy S5 (Android version 4.4.2 and Parse 1.4.1).

In my Activity, I show the Fragment here (called `PostViewListViewFragment`):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new PostViewListViewFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @VedPrakash for helping me fix this.

In case it helps anyone, I fixed the problem by replacing the *fragment* not *adding* it. So I changed this line **from**:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new PostViewListViewFragment()).commit();
```

**to**:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PostViewListViewFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/post_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scrollbars="none"    >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your adapter like this:

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
      // configure view holder
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    String s = names[position];
    holder.text.setText(s);

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

PS:You should watch this Google IO [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) about Listview,and here is the [slides](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf).

Comment: What is `ViewHolder`?

Comment: You should watch this Google IO [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) about Listview,and here is the [slides](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for those resources. Since I'm using the [Parse Android API](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide), I don't think this would work.

Answer (score 0):

First create a ViewHolder class

```
static class ViewHolder {

        protected TextView usernameTextView;
    }
```

Then change your getItemView method like below

```
public View getItemView (Post post, View convertView , ViewGroup parent)
{

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post_view, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.usernameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_text_view);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        convertView.setTag(R.id.user_name_text_view, viewHolder.usernameTextView);


    }

    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.usernameTextView.setText(post.getNotes()); // some string


    return convertView;


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Also, you should switch the first parameter from `int position` to `Post post` and assigning `viewHolder` to `null` is redundant.

Comment: What is wrong if you assign object to null? Will you please expound?

Comment: Nothing. It would behave the same way, but since you always initialized `viewHolder` in either the `if` block or the `else` block, it's redundant to initialize it to null. The `viewHolder` would always be assigned before the next time it is read.

Comment: @lschlessinger,Try to remove this line :  convertView.setTag(R.id.user_name_text_view, viewHolder.usernameTextView); and check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your list item layout -

***Change it to this*** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/link_blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Probably you have extra background for each list item set that is causing such effect.
Alter and watch.

Hope this gives you idea!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This specific layout doesn't work though. What did you change besides the ParseImageView background? I'll keep playing around with the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your list view layout height to match_parent.

Comment: Do you mean the ListView with the ID `post_list_view`?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.